# Vue component unknown despite being registered

Tags: javascript, templates, vue.js

I am trying to compose a component inside another like this:

```
<prompt :users="users">
...
  <dataset v-for="ds in users" :user="user"></dataset>
...
</prompt>
```

But apparently I'm not registering it properly:

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <dataset> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option. 
(found in root instance)
```

Here's how I'm trying to register it:

app.js

```
Vue.component('prompt', {
    props: ['userdata', 'users'],
    template: '#prompt-template',    
    components: {
        'dataset': {
            props: ['userdataset', 'user'],
            template: '#dataset-template',
        }        
    }
});
```

Finally, the templates:

```
 <template id="dataset-template">
      <li>{{ user}}</li>
  </template>

  <template id="prompt-template">
      <transition name="modal">
          <div class="modal-mask">
              <div class="modal-wrapper">
                  <div class="modal-container">

                      <div class="modal-header">
                          <slot name="header">
                              default header
                          </slot>
                      </div>

                      <div class="modal-body">
                          <slot name="body">

                          </slot>
                      </div>

                      <div class="modal-footer">
                          <slot name="footer">
                              default footer
                              <button class="modal-default-button" @click="$emit('close')">
                                  OK
                              </button>
                          </slot>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </transition>
  </template>
```

Are there any steps I'm missing?  I can't figure out how the component isn't being registered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you use the `dataset` component as a slot within the `prompt` component. While the Vue vm tries to figure out the component tree it  will recognize the `dataset` component which it does not know. **Subcomponents are used in the component template but not within slots.** You have to register the `dataset` component within the Vue vm like you did for the `prompt` component. Try this

```
Vue.component('promp', { ... })
Vue.component('dataset', { ... })
```

It also make sense to register the components on the same level since the templates of the components are also registered on the same level (next to each other).
Compare it to [the example you mentioned in another answers comment](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/svg.html): Here the subcomponent `axis-label` ***is only used within the template of the parent `polygraph` component***. This is valid since now the component is in contract to figure out it sub components not the vue-vm.

## In other words:

It should be possible to pass components into the slot of any component `A` which are not subcomponents of `A`. Therefore all components passed to slots of a component should be available to the vue vm.

## Thumb rule could be

if a component does not appear within another components template, it is not a subcomponent.

Comment: In that case, shouldn't removing the slot tag from ```<dataset>``` make the error go away?  I tried removing it but the error still comes up

Comment: It is maybe a bit confusing. The essence is that if you use components within the main element of the application, they should be registred at vue-vm level. Maybe sometimes you want to display the `dataset` component outside the prompt? `dataset` is not really a subcomponent of `prompt` isn't it? It is more like a component you want to display within the `prompt` component which is why you pass it by slots.

Comment: actually, ```dataset``` is supposed to be a subcomponent, very similar to the SVG example I linked to.  That's why I registered it in the prompt component.

Comment: but then you cannot use it as a slot, you can **only** use it within the template of the prompt component. Like: ` <template id="prompt-template"> .... .... <dataset...></dataset></template>`.

Comment: Yeah I got that, I'm not using it as a slot anymore.  I took that tag out and it's still coming up with the same error

Comment: It has nothing to do with the slot, you need the slot to pass components into another component. Which is what you want to do here. **but** this means that dataset is **not** a subcomponent. If it is a subcomponent you **must** use  it within the template like a said in the comment above. I mean wouldn't it be nice in the future to use the prompt component with different content? maybe somedays you want `<prompt><bla></bla></prompt>`. Or maybe in the future you want to use the `dataset` component at another place?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134236/discussion-between-keksnicoh-and-david-j).